# Cannot Access GitLab on Localhost Using Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, dockerfile, localhost

I've installed GitLab on my Windows laptop through Ubuntu with the commands listed at the following website: [TheNewStack](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-deploy-gitlab-server-using-docker-and-ubuntu-server-22-04/)

My docker compose file is the following:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    web:
        image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest'
        container_name: 'gitlab-server'
        restart: always
        hostname: 'localhost'
        environment:
        GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
            external_url 'http://localhost'
            gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
            gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "localhost"
            gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "MYUSER"
            gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "PASSWORD"
            gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "localhost"
            gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
            gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
            gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
            gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'USER@DOMAIN.COM'
            gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'USER@DOMAIN.COM'
        ports:
            - '80:20'
            - '443:443'
            - '22:22'
            - '587:587'
        volumes:
            - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
            - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
            - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
        shm_size: '256m'
```

I'm completely new to docker containers and this file is just copy/pasted/edited from a website. I'm not sure if something in the compose file is wrong, such as smtp_address or domain, or I'm using the wrong ip address/ports when typing in the URL on my browser. Docker shows that it is running but when I click any of the ports, it says "This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" or some other error message depending on the port I put.

I tried http:localhost:PORTNUMBER with different port numbers and I tried my host ip address. I believe there might be a ip address linked with docker but I am unsure where to put it and what to do with that.

Note:
When running "docker ps", I get the following:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED          STATUS                            PORTS                                                                                        NAMES
2778e1ab6c8e   gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest   "/assets/wrapper"   12 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:22->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:45->45/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:587->587/tcp, 80/tcp   gitlab-server
a4117bf1ea12   gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest   "/assets/wrapper"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes (healthy)           22/tcp, 80/tcp, 443/tcp                                                                      sleepy_payne
```

Comment: What worries me is why you have two containers

Comment: I deleted one of them. I only have the top one now.

Comment: ports:
            - '80:20'  did you 80:80